# iOS: how to prompt for user consent without clicking any button

Tags: ios

I'm writing an app where a user can store a list of documents. When the user adds a new document whose name is already in the list, I'd like to prompt the user for her/his consent to replace the old document. I've looked at UIActionSheet but looks like it should be used when the user clicks some sort of button. UIAlertView is more like warning the user "The document will be replaced, no matter you like or not." So my question is: what's the best way in this case to prompt the user for consent?

Comment: Using an alert view, when worded properly, is not more like a warning. And you do not need a button to do an action sheet. What makes you think that?

Comment: I'm thinking that way because the action sheet has to be generated from a view, and it looks like most views are buttons. So that said, I can write code to respond to the button clicked in a UIAlertView, right?

Comment: An action sheet can be presented from any view, including a view controller's view. And yes, you can of course respond to alert view buttons. See the docs for `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

Comment: Thank you! Please answer this question again below so that I can officially accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alerts can be used to ask the user to confirm an action. It is done all of the time. Simply implement the proper alert view delegate methods to respond to the user's choice.

Action sheets can be shown at any time with any need for a button to trigger such an event. The action sheet provides several options for displaying the action sheet.

Comment: One more question though: does alert view block the main thread? I'm surrounding the alert view show code with a loop, so the users will be prompted for each of the duplicated document.

Comment: No, alert view does't block the main thread but the alert covers the whole user interface forcing the user to make a choice before doing anything else. Your code must show the alert and then be done. You handle the user's answer in completely different code. Your code can't "sit and wait" for the answer. You need to write your code with event driven design in mind.